# Optimizing script that modifies ACL on files in network share recursively

Tags: powershell

( Hi there! First-ever post here, so please don't bash me too much if you find it inane :) )

I have a task where i have to recursively set "inheritance" on all the files and folders that are stored within root folders on a file share, i.e. copy ACL from root folder and apply it on all of it's children.

The task is complicated by two issues: first - some of the children either don't have an owner or it's not Admins group, and second - some of the files full paths exceed the 256 symbols limit and thus can't be worked with by regular means (both of the problems arose after the share was moved from one NAS to another with a ROBOCOPY script that was apparently less than ideal).

These two issues deny me the use of GUI with "Replace all child permissions with inheritable permissions from this object" option checked, since at some point (sometimes after a few hours of processing) it throws an "Access denied" error and you either have to Skip on every single file or cancel the process entirely.

To circumvent these issues i wrote a script that elevates privileges on current process (C# code block shamelessly borrowed from [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Set-Owner-ff4db177) script with minor modification) and allow you to set admin group as owner of the file/folder being processed, which in turn enables you to modify its ACL, while children with long names are grabbed and processed in identical way using DOS device path syntax.

In other words, the script does just what i want it to do. But it's doing it painfully slow, because each of the folders on our share contains hundreds of thousands of files, each of which is processed individually on each iteration within the process block of my script. Much slower than GUI, if only GUI worked for me.

So i thought maybe some Powershell gurus on StackOverflow would suggest a way to optimize that clunky script of mine & make it run faster? :) If GUI does it faster, there must be a way, right?

```
$CSScriptBlock = @' advapi32.dll functions here that enable required privileges '@
function Adjust-Privilege { ... Add-Type $CSScriptBlock etc etc }

$root = "\\server\share\folder"

function restore-inheritance {
param(
[parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$True)]
[Alias('FullName')]
[string[]]$Path
)
    BEGIN ### enable privileges, get ACL from root folder
    { 
        "SeRestorePrivilege","SeBackupPrivilege","SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" | Adjust-Privilege

        $acl = Get-ACL $root
        ### remove explicit ACEs
        $acl.Access | Where {$_.isinherited -eq $false} | % {
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($_)
        }
    }

    PROCESS ### try to apply that ACL to children, set owner on failure and retry
    {   
        $DirOwner = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
        $DirOwner.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'Builtin\Administrators')
        $FileOwner = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity
        $FileOwner.SetOwner([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]'Builtin\Administrators')
         
        $path = $input.fullName    
        $litpath = "\\?\UNC" + $path.substring(1)

        if ([bool](get-item $path)) {
            try {
                Write-Host "Attempting to fix inheritance on [ $path ]"
                Set-Acl $path $acl -EA Stop
                }
            catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException],`
                  [System.UnauthorizedAccessException],`
                  [System.IO.IOException] {
                Write-Host "Attempting to overwrite ownership of [ $path ]"
                $item = get-item $path
                if (!$item.PSIsContainer) {
                    $item.SetAccessControl($FileOwner)
                    Set-Acl $path $acl
                    }
                else {
                    $item.SetAccessControl($DirOwner)
                    Set-Acl $path $acl
                    }
                }
        }
        ### kicks in only when file is unreachable via regular path
        else {
            try {
                Write-Host "Attempting to fix inheritance on [ $litpath ]" -F Yellow
                Set-Acl -LiteralPath $litpath $acl -EA Stop
                }
            catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException],`
                  [System.UnauthorizedAccessException],`
                  [System.IO.IOException] {
                Write-Host "Attempting to overwrite ownership of [ $litpath ]" -F Yellow
                $item = get-item -LiteralPath $litpath
                if (!$item.PSIsContainer) {
                    $item.SetAccessControl($FileOwner)
                    Set-Acl -LiteralPath $litpath $acl
                    }
                else {
                    $item.SetAccessControl($DirOwner)
                    Set-Acl -LiteralPath $litpath $acl
                    }
                }
            } 
    }

    END ### disable privileges
    {
        "SeRestorePrivilege","SeBackupPrivilege","SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege" | Adjust-Privilege -Disable
    }
}

get-childitem $root -Recurse -EA Stop | restore-inheritance
```

Comment: [1] win10 has an option to allow longer file names. do a search for `Enable long file name support in Windows 10`. ///// [2] there is a stackexchange site for this >>> Code Review Stack Exchange — https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We're stuck on Win7. :(
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: arg! you may need to use the Code Review site to get anything useful, then. ///// as an aside, i was taught that one should NOT do anything with the privs of a SHARE ... that should be "everyone, everything". instead, one should work with the underlying filesystem and apply group privs whenever possible ... and user privs only when needed & preferably by inheritance, not by "this item". i suspect i would clear all the privs & replace them with new ones ... all of them inheritable, if possible.